# How to select a dynamically generated form element in jquery / javascript using its ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am trying to create a row of 3 form fields dynamically when the user clicks on the ADD button / plus symbol .

[image]

**Javascript code used to create the form elements is below  :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var field_counter = 1;
    var field_limit = 5;
    species = document.getElementById('species');
    breed = document.getElementById('breed');


    function addInput(divName){

        if (field_counter == field_limit)  {
            alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + field_counter + " inputs");
        }
        else {

            var dynamic_species = 'species'+field_counter; //dynamic id for species
            var dynamic_breed = 'breed'+field_counter;  //dynamic id for breed
            var dynamic_quantity = 'quantity'+field_counter; //dynammic id for quantity
            var dynamicForm = '<div class="form-group"><div class="col-md-4"><label for="'+dynamic_species+'">Animal Type</label><select class="form-control input-sm '+dynamic_species+'" id="'+dynamic_species+'"><option></option></select></div>';
            dynamicForm+='<div class="form-group"><div class="col-md-4"><label for="'+dynamic_breed+'">Breed</label><select class="form-control input-sm '+dynamic_breed+'"  id="'+dynamic_breed+'"><option></option></select></div>';
            dynamicForm+='<div class="form-group"><div class="col-md-2"><label for="'+dynamic_quantity+'">Quantity</label><input type="number" name="quantity_export" id="'+dynamic_quantity+'" class="form-control input-sm '+dynamic_quantity+'" /></div>';
            var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
            newdiv.innerHTML =  dynamicForm;
            document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
            document.getElementById(dynamic_species).innerHTML = species.innerHTML;
            document.getElementById(dynamic_breed).innerHTML = breed.innerHTML;
            field_counter++;

        }
    }
</script>
<div class="col-md-2" >
    <label for="">&nbsp;</label>
    <i onclick="addInput('dynamicInput');" style="cursor: pointer; border: none;" class="fa fa-plus form-control input-sm">Add</i>

</div>
```

Using the above code am creating the form fields "Animal Type , Breed and Quantity ", all together in a row as shown in the image . Maximum number of  rows that can be added is limited to the value of the variable "field_limit".

The value of the drop downs are initially populated from the parent drop down using the code :

```
species = document.getElementById('species');
breed = document.getElementById('breed'); 
document.getElementById(dynamic_species).innerHTML = species.innerHTML;
document.getElementById(dynamic_breed).innerHTML = breed.innerHTML;
```

**Question :** How can I select the dynamically generated ID of the new form fields .

[image]

Here is the script am using to select the first row of form fields which is in the HTML when the page loads for the first time :

```
$("#species").change(function(){
        $('#breed').empty();
        //alert($(this).val());
        var param = {'id':$(this).val()};
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : '<?php echo base_url();?>select_breed',
            dataType : 'json',
            data: param,
            success : function(data)
            {
                var select = $('#breed');
                select.empty().append(data);
            },
            error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);

            }
        });

    });
```

The second row of form fields are created dynamically with the following ID's

> First Field : Animal Type : `ID="species1"`
>
> Second Field : Breed : `ID="breed1"`
>
> Third Field : Quantity : `ID="quantity1"`

I am not able to select the dynamically generated form fields using the jquery selector :- eg: `$("#species1").change(function(){});` ,  it is not working .

**What I am trying to do ?**

I need to get the value of these fields using its ID attribute. Any help would be highly appreciated . Thank you .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`event delegation`](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for dynamic generated content like so :

```
// change `document` to top level parent that existed on page or
// parent container
$(document).on("change", "#species1", function(){...});
```

Answer (score 1):

Thats because they do not exists yet when binding to it's change event.

You could add the event listener in the `add_input` function, or use a more abstract event handler:

```
$("form").on("change", ".species", function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
    ...
});
```

This will require you to drop the ID's and use `class` attributes instead. Which is the way to go by my opinion.

You can attach the ID's using `$(speciesElement).attr("data-id", id)`.